# How to ask HR for overdue reimbursement?

Tags: communication, human-resources

A company representative explicitly said I would be receiving my traveling reimbursement by 30 Nov, but I have not yet received it.

In addition to this, they sent me an offer via email, I said I would accept it contingent on looking at the contract, and they haven't sent that either. All this communication happened about a month ago.

As a non-native speaker, I'm not sure how to send a polite but firm email reminding that they're due to send me reimbursement and the contract.

Comment: Do you currently work at this company, or is this someplace you are applying? If they said you would receive it by the 30th, I would say it's overdue, but not *long* overdue. Just follow up and ask them about it.

Comment: Related: [Still haven't got my travel expenses reimbursement three weeks after interviewing. Should I contact HR?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56374/still-havent-got-my-travel-expenses-reimbursement-three-weeks-after-interviewin) and [Two months since the interview - still haven't received my travel reimbursement](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/94167/two-months-since-the-interview-still-havent-received-my-travel-reimbursement)

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry too much about sounding insistent. HR in any company can be extraordinarily slow from my experience. Just send a follow up email with your original email copied bellow, asking for a status on your reimbursement. As for the offer, a similar approach is what I would suggest. Just send an email asking about the offer letter. As long as you're businesslike in your emails, you won't come off as rude. (E.g):

Hello [HR person],

I am contacting you about the status of the reimbursement for travel expenses that we discussed earlier (copied bellow), I was wondering when that would go through? In addition, I was wondering about the status of my offer letter so I can review the contract in more detail.

Thanks for your time,

[your name]